# How can I retreive the main body of a question using the StackExchange API? I can only retreive the title of a question

Tags: python, json, python-requests, openai-api

```
import requests, openai

# Set your Stack Exchange API key
stack_exchange_api_key = 'your_stack_exchange_api_key'

# Set your OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = 'your_openai_api_key'

# Step 1: Retrieve new unanswered questions with the Python tag from Stack Exchange API

# Set parameters for Stack Exchange API
stack_exchange_endpoint = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions'
stack_exchange_params = {
    'site': 'stackoverflow',
    'key': stack_exchange_api_key,
    'order': 'desc',
    'sort': 'creation',
    'tagged': 'python',
    'answers': 0,  # Filter for unanswered questions
}

# Make the API request to Stack Exchange
stack_exchange_response = requests.get(stack_exchange_endpoint, params=stack_exchange_params)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if stack_exchange_response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the response JSON
    stack_exchange_data = stack_exchange_response.json()

    # Step 2: Ask ChatGPT for answers to each question
```

How can I retreieve the main body of the question? I cannot see any key in the json response that corresponds to that main part of the question. I can only get the title. Do I need to use the question_id and make some other request?

Comment: [Why can't I use Artificial Intelligence tools to generate answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy)

Comment: This is just entirely for educational purposing. Im not actually planning on using this program

Comment: Youve made an incorrect assumption that im going to use this script to answer stackoverflow question with chatgpt. Its for my own personal  and educational use

Comment: I made no such assumption. I just leave the comment there so you (and any other people who may read the question) are aware that submitting AI-generated answers may have some consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Worked out how to retreive the body content by using the filter "withbody" which returns the body fields

```
# Set parameters for Stack Exchange API
stack_exchange_endpoint = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions'
stack_exchange_params = {
    'site': 'stackoverflow',
    'key': stack_exchange_api_key,
    'filter': 'withbody',
    'order': 'desc',
    'sort': 'creation',
    'tagged': 'python',
    'answers': 0,  # Filter for unanswered questions
}
```

can now retrieve question body content this way.

```
print(f"Question Title: {question['title']}")
print(f"Question Body: {question['body']}")
```

The output looks like this

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>python openOverflow.py
    <p>I created a neural network model that predicts certain properties from coordinates.</p>
    <p>Using that model, I want to find the coordinates that minimize the properties in optuna's NSGA-II sampler.</p>
    <p>Normally, we would generate a random initial population by specifying a range of coordinates.</p>
    <p>However, I would like to include the coordinates used to construct the neural network as part of the initial population.</p>
    <p>Is there any way to do it?</p>
    <p>The following is a sample code.
    I want to include a part of the value specified by myself in the &quot;#&quot; part like x, y = [3, 2], [4.2, 1.4]</p>
    <pre><code>import optuna
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline

    import warnings
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')

    def objective(trial):
        x = trial.suggest_uniform(&quot;x&quot;, 0, 5)   #This is the normal way
        y = trial.suggest_uniform(&quot;y&quot;, 0, 3)   #This is the normal way
        v0 = 4 * x ** 2 + 4 * y ** 2
        v1 = (x - 5) ** 2 + (y - 5) ** 2
        return v0, v1

    study = optuna.multi_objective.create_study(
        directions=[&quot;minimize&quot;, &quot;minimize&quot;],
        sampler=optuna.multi_objective.samplers.NSGAIIMultiObjectiveSampler()
    )

    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100)
    </code></pre>

    **Question Title: Is there a way to specify the initial population in optuna&#39;s NSGA-II?**


**Question Body: <p>I created a neural network model that predicts certain properties from coordinates.</p>
    <p>Using that model, I want to find the coordinates that minimize the properties in optuna's NSGA-II sampler.</p>
    <p>Normally, we would generate a random initial population by specifying a range of coordinates.</p>
    <p>However, I would like to include the coordinates used to construct the neural network as part of the initial population.</p>
    <p>Is there any way to do it?</p>
    <p>The following is a sample code.
    I want to include a part of the value specified by myself in the &quot;#&quot; part like x, y = [3, 2], [4.2, 1.4]</p>
    <pre><code>import optuna
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline

    import warnings
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')

    def objective(trial):
        x = trial.suggest_uniform(&quot;x&quot;, 0, 5)   #This is the normal way
        y = trial.suggest_uniform(&quot;y&quot;, 0, 3)   #This is the normal way
        v0 = 4 * x ** 2 + 4 * y ** 2
        v1 = (x - 5) ** 2 + (y - 5) ** 2
        return v0, v1

    study = optuna.multi_objective.create_study(
        directions=[&quot;minimize&quot;, &quot;minimize&quot;],
        sampler=optuna.multi_objective.samplers.NSGAIIMultiObjectiveSampler()
    )

    study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100)
    </code></pre>**

    ChatGPT Answer: Sorry, but we do not know the answer to your question.
    --------------------------------------------------
    <p>I have reactjs application for frontend, and nodejs application for backend end, i have one other application that is using flask and communicating with frontend for some AI purpose. But for some reason we want to bundle react and python application, we do not want to put python app on server. So my questions:</p>
    <p>1- What is the best way to make installer that create executable file having both react and python app</p>
    <p>2- I have used nodejs childprocess to run python application but it is showing command prompt, which i want to be a background process.</p>
    <p>3- Since i have bundled python app in the package, so i don't think flask is needed for internal communication with front end. So what are the other choices?</p>
    <p>Thanks</p>

    Question Title: Best way to make electron, react and python application in a package
    Question Body: <p>I have reactjs application for frontend, and nodejs application for backend end, i have one other application that is using flask and communicating with frontend for some AI purpose. But for some reason we want to bundle react and python application, we do not want to put python app on server. So my questions:</p>
    <p>1- What is the best way to make installer that create executable file having both react and python app</p>
    <p>2- I have used nodejs childprocess to run python application but it is showing command prompt, which i want to be a background process.</p>
    <p>3- Since i have bundled python app in the package, so i don't think flask is needed for internal communication with front end. So what are the other choices?</p>
    <p>Thanks</p>

    ChatGPT Answer: ?

    There is no one "best" way to package an electron, react, and python application. However, one approach would be to use a tool like Electron Forge to create a basic Electron boilerplate, then add in React and python asdependencies.
    --------------------------------------------------
    <p>In my Django view I have 3 models and I want to do a conditional based on where a variable is coming from.</p>
    <p>I have tried...</p>
    <pre class="lang-py prettyprint-override"><code>    if (type(variable)) is ModelA:
            do this...
    </code></pre>
    <p>If I do...</p>
    <pre class="lang-py prettyprint-override"><code>    print(type(variable))
        it prints out '&lt;class 'app.models.ModelA'&gt;'
    </code></pre>
    <p>But the conditional never kicks in. I'm not sure what I am missing.</p>

    Question Title: Is it possible to have a conditional statement distinguish which model a Python variable is coming from?
    Question Body: <p>In my Django view I have 3 models and I want to do a conditional based on where a variable is coming from.</p>
    <p>I have tried...</p>
    <pre class="lang-py prettyprint-override"><code>    if (type(variable)) is ModelA:
            do this...
    </code></pre>
    <p>If I do...</p>
    <pre class="lang-py prettyprint-override"><code>    print(type(variable))
        it prints out '&lt;class 'app.models.ModelA'&gt;'
    </code></pre>
    <p>But the conditional never kicks in. I'm not sure what I am missing.</p>

    ChatGPT Answer: Yes, it is possible to have a conditional statement distinguish which model a Python variable is coming from.
    --------------------------------------------------
    <p>I have implemented the python code to extract the info of a particular account like username, post details using Instagram graph api I wan to implement the same to 5 Instagram accounts which are public, if possible
    using only the graph api of a single account to access 5 accounts.</p>
    <p>this i was trying for a single Instagram account--</p>
    <pre><code>import requests

    # Replace with your Facebook access token
    access_token = &quot; &quot;

    # Replace with your Instagram Business Account ID
    instagram_account_id = &quot;&quot;

    # Get user media (posts) for Instagram using the combined API
    media_url = f&quot;https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{instagram_account_id}/media&quot;
    params_media = {
        &quot;access_token&quot;: access_token,
        &quot;fields&quot;: &quot;id,caption,media_type,thumbnail_url,permalink,timestamp,like_count,comments_count,media_like_count,media_comments_count,impressions_1d,username,name,location&quot;,
    }
    response_media = requests.get(media_url, params=params_media)

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response_media.status_code == 200:
        media_data = response_media.json()

        # Get username and name from the first post
        first_post = media_data.get(&quot;data&quot;, [])[0]
        username = first_post.get(&quot;username&quot;, &quot;&quot;)
        name = first_post.get(&quot;name&quot;, &quot;&quot;)

        # Print username and name only once at the beginning
        print(f&quot;Username: {username}&quot;)
        print(f&quot;Name: {name}&quot;)

        # Get profile information for the Instagram Business Account
        profile_url = f&quot;https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{instagram_account_id}?fields=profile_picture_url,followers_count,follows_count&amp;access_token={access_token}&quot;
        response_profile = requests.get(profile_url)

        if response_profile.status_code == 200:
            profile_data = response_profile.json()
            profile_picture_url = profile_data.get(&quot;profile_picture_url&quot;, &quot;&quot;)
            followers_count = profile_data.get(&quot;followers_count&quot;, 0)
            follows_count = profile_data.get(&quot;follows_count&quot;, 0)
            print(f&quot;Profile Picture URL: {profile_picture_url}&quot;)
            print(f&quot;Followers Count: {followers_count}&quot;)
            print(f&quot;Following Count: {follows_count}&quot;)

        else:
            print(f&quot;Error getting profile information: {response_profile.status_code} - {response_profile.text}&quot;)

        # Print user media for Instagram
        print(f&quot;\nUser Media:&quot;)
        num_posts = len(media_data.get(&quot;data&quot;, []))
        print(f&quot;Number of Posts: {num_posts}&quot;)

        for post in media_data.get(&quot;data&quot;, []):
            post_id = post.get(&quot;id&quot;)
            caption = post.get(&quot;caption&quot;, &quot;&quot;)
            timestamp = post.get(&quot;timestamp&quot;, &quot;&quot;)
            like_count = post.get(&quot;like_count&quot;, 0)
            comments_count = post.get(&quot;comments_count&quot;, 0)
            media_type = post.get(&quot;media_type&quot;, &quot;&quot;)
            media_permalink = post.get(&quot;permalink&quot;, &quot;&quot;)
            media_like_count = post.get(&quot;media_like_count&quot;, 0)
            media_comments_count = post.get(&quot;media_comments_count&quot;, 0)
            impressions_1d = post.get(&quot;impressions_1d&quot;, 0)
            location = post.get(&quot;location&quot;, {}).get(&quot;name&quot;, &quot;No Location&quot;)

            print(f&quot;\nPost ID: {post_id}&quot;)
            print(f&quot;Caption: {caption}&quot;)
            print(f&quot;Timestamp: {timestamp}&quot;)
            print(f&quot;Likes Count: {like_count}&quot;)
            print(f&quot;Comments Count: {comments_count}&quot;)
            print(f&quot;Media Type: {media_type}&quot;)
            print(f&quot;Media Permalink: {media_permalink}&quot;)
            print(f&quot;Media Like Count: {media_like_count}&quot;)
            print(f&quot;Media Comments Count: {media_comments_count}&quot;)
            print(f&quot;Impressions 1D: {impressions_1d}&quot;)
            print(f&quot;Location: {location}&quot;)

        # Print list of followers
        followers_url = f&quot;https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{instagram_account_id}/followers&quot;
        params_followers = {
            &quot;access_token&quot;: access_token,
            &quot;fields&quot;: &quot;name&quot;,
        }
        response_followers = requests.get(followers_url, params=params_followers)

        if response_followers.status_code == 200:
            followers_data = response_followers.json()
            followers_list = followers_data.get(&quot;data&quot;, [])

            if followers_list:
                print(&quot;\nFollowers:&quot;)
                for follower in followers_list:
                    follower_name = follower.get(&quot;name&quot;, &quot;&quot;)
                    print(f&quot;- {follower_name}&quot;)
            else:
                print(&quot;\nNo followers found.&quot;)

    else:
        print(f&quot;Error: {response_media.status_code} - {response_media.text}&quot;)

    </code></pre>



<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Nice work. Can you show the output? Ex: `stack_exchange_response`